# pass data among processes in python

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I'm trying to get familiar with subprocess.Popen mechanism.

In the bellow example, I try to run netstat then run grep on the output.

```
netstat = subprocess.Popen("netstat -nptl".split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen("grep 192.168.46.134".split(), stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

However this does not result in a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the first process' `stdout` as the `stdin` for the second process:

```
import subprocess

netstat = subprocess.Popen("netstat -nptl".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen("grep 192.168.46.134".split(), stdin=netstat.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = grep.communicate()
print stdout # this is a string containing the output
```

Comment: I'm getting "broken pipe" error... :(

Comment: Weird, I just tried it (with slightly different commands since I'm presently on windows) and it worked just fine. You're calling `grep.communicate()` after, right?

Comment: I didn't run grep.communicate(), why it is necessary?

Comment: Then how did you run it? You get the desired output by running `stdout, stderr = grep.communicate()`.

Comment: I'm not sure regarding the stdout, stderr = grep.communicate().
Can you please edit the answer to include this? I'm totally unfamiliar to Python...

Comment: Updated. The `communicate()` method returns a tuple of 2 elements, and you unpack them into individual variables `stdout` and `stderr`. You then use the `stdout` however you want, it's just a string.